# Ion-content transition issue

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

We developed apps with `ionic` and `angularjs`, but we have some issue with transition content it makes content comes down from top, but it is very slow transition, and have lag.

I think it causes the `ion-content`, when I remove it transition was gone, but I can't scrolling the page.
Is it possible to remove transition `ion-content`?
and how I can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible to remove <ion-content> tag, can you please post your code in github or codepen to have a look